# Glassfish4: How to load external derby database in JDK8 outside default glassfish derby directory?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, derby, java-8

i installed JDK8.0 beta , with Netbeans8 Beta+Glassfish4.0

the glassfish & JavaDB Server using by default this location for setup new derby databases :
`C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby`

when i tried to change JavaDB Database Location to something like:
`G:\DerbyDatabases`

and restart the JavaDB Server , then this error occured and couldn't start the derby server again

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.startNetworkServer(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown
>   Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.RuntimeException    at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.services.io.FileUtil.limitAccessToOwnerViaACLs(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.services.io.FileUtil.limitAccessToOwner(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.PBmakeFileHPW(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.makeFileHPW(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.createDefaultStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.makeStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.stream.SingleStream.boot(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startSystemModule(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.(Unknown Source)     ... 6
>   more

i think that it because of my Jre8 policy setting but i don't know how to solve it, so this is my current java.policy file contents which may help :

> // Standard extensions get all permissions by default
>
> grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
>           permission java.security.AllPermission; };
>
> // default permissions granted to all domains
>
> grant {
>           // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
>           // method that takes no argument.
>           // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
>           // backwards compatible.
>           // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
>           // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
>           // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
>           // See the API specification of java.lang.Thread.stop() for more
>           // information.
>           permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";
>
> ```
>     // allows anyone to listen on dynamic ports
>     permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";
>
>     // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone
>
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";
>
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";
>
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
>     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
> ```
>
> permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen,resolve";
>   permission java.sql.SQLPermission "deregisterDriver"; };

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've encountered DERBY-6410: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6410

The problem is that your "G:\" path has been defined using the Windows "subst" command: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

There's something wrong in Java's IO utility classes which cause Derby problems when accessing such a substituted path.

You'll have to find a workaround for now, as that Derby issue does not appear to have a fix yet.

Can you use a different filesystem for your databases, without creating the path with subst?